# JMeter Warning msg "WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release"

Tags: jmeter

After switching from JM v5.4.3 to JM v.5.6.2 I am noticing this warning msg each time I launch Jmeter-
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzTeu.png)

Wondering what is this about and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have some [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which are not using [ServiceLoader](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/5885) for discovery and registering.

For the time being you can just ignore the warning (unless you're willing to patch all the plugins)

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article you should always use the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c) (or whatever is the latest stable verson of JMeter which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)